# jQuery Multiselect plug in - noneSelectText won't display when using single select

Tags: jquery, multi-select

When I use "multiple: false", the noneSelectedText is not being displayed in my dropdown list.
It will display the first item instead already selected. Here is my code:

```
    $("#FilterBatch").multiselect
    ({
        header: true,
        noneSelectedText: "Select Batch",
        selectedList: 1,
        multiple: false,
        checkAllText: "", 
        uncheckAllText: "",
        click: function (event, ui) {
            FilterBatch_Change(ui.value);
        }
    });
```

I am having to add the text myself by doing the append below:

```
$('#FilterBatch').append($('<option></option>').attr('value', '-1').text('Select a Batch'));
```

But after I do a loop to pre-populate all items, when I click the first item it will return me a -1 as value. If I click it second time it will return me the right value. It's very weird.

I would like to use the noneSelectedText without having to add the text string myself.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add "multiple" in the html tag:

```
<div><select id=\"FilterStatus\" style=\"width:200px;\" multiple=\"multiple;\"></select></div>";
```